# How to get an game object to instantiate lower than where It's created?

Tags: c#, unity, transformation

When I press the collider where my allies spawn I want for them to spawn a little bit lower when I instantiate. I have tried to use Vector 3 and GetComponent, but It gives this error:

'Assets/Scripts/PlaceMonster.cs(26,33): error CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer'

I just want for my allies to spawn a little bit lower than the collider, but I'm stumped on what's the problem.

```
void OnMouseUp () {
    theAllyMenu.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    if (canPlaceAlly ()) {
        ally = (GameObject)
            //GetComponent<Transform>().transformPic = transformPic;
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - -5, transform.position.z);
            Instantiate (allyPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    } 

}
```

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your problem, please hit the green checkmark to accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ally = (GameObject)`

...is a syntax error. You need to comment this line just like you did the one below it.

The problem is on that line, but because it's so malformed (no semicolon at the end), the compiler doesn't recognise it and assumes the problem is on the next line,

`transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - -5, transform.position.z);`

...which actually has no problems, of course.

---

Really, this is why formatting is so important. If you had tab-indented your code correctly:

```
void OnMouseUp () {
    theAllyMenu.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    if (canPlaceAlly ()) {
        ally = (GameObject)
        //GetComponent<Transform>().transformPic = transformPic;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - -5, transform.position.z);
        Instantiate (allyPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    } 
}
```

Or even better, kept what is one statement, on one line,

`ally = (GameObject) GetComponent<Transform>().transformPic = transformPic;`

Then you might have seen the problem straight away.

Comment: I don't know if it exactly worked. Sure the ally goes down like It's supposed to, but the picture of the ally in ally selection menu (TD-game), becomes the ally that is placed and you can buy infinite allies when you press the lowest ally. Upgrade also doesn't work. Otherwise it does what It's supposed to kind of. Thanks.

Comment: @SleepySleeper. Oh, it _did_ work or you would not be able to compile your code at all. Your other problems are separate ones, and should be asked as new questions. I'm sure you'll get the help you need. GLHF.